# Combine separate HTML and PHP MYSQL form into one file

Tags: php, html, mysql

The reasons behind my needing this are complicated but I have a currently working HTML form that inserts a row into my MYSQL database. However... I need to combine the two separate processes into one HTML file but after many attempts at arranging the code cannot come to a working solution. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="user_text" id="hiddenField" value="x" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the related process.php file:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    //mysql credentials
    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_username = "*";
    $mysql_password = "*";
    $mysql_database = "*";

    $u_name = $_POST["id"];
    $u_text = $_POST["user_text"];

    if (empty($u_name)){
        die("Please enter your id");
    }

    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }   

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users_data (contractor_id, status) VALUES(?, ?)"); //prepare sql insert query
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $u_name, $u_text); //bind values and execute insert query


}
?>
```

I know this isn't the right way to do things but it isn't for a public site, more a personal logging project. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Even if you just copy&pasted those two snippets of code just one after another into the file, it should basically work - well apart from the fact that you don't actually execute the query, but in that regard it would not have worked with the code as shown in two separate files either. A comment _saying_ that a query was executed on that line doesn't actually make it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply have a file like this:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    process();
}
else {
    show_form();
}


function show_form () {
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="user_text" id="hiddenField" value="x" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
}

function process () {

    //mysql credentials
    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_username = "*";
    $mysql_password = "*";
    $mysql_database = "*";

    $u_name = $_POST["id"];
    $u_text = $_POST["user_text"];

    if (empty($u_name)){
        die("Please enter your id");
    }

    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }   

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users_data (contractor_id, status) VALUES(?, ?)"); //prepare sql insert query
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $u_name, $u_text); //bind values and execute insert query


}
```

If you do not set the`action` for form, by default, it submits to itself

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what I am looking for thank you! However it's returning a syntax error on line 5 but I can't figure out why. Any ideas?